# How do I apply a condition on a related table for the last records?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables related this way:

- **Store** (a store has many products)
- **Products** (a product has many product stock histories)
- **Product_Stock_History**

**Products** has a field named *status*. It has the current stock status. The possible values are 1 (in stock) or any other value (not in stock).

**Product_Stock_History** also has a *status* field, with the same possible values.

---

The query I want to build in SQL is:

For all stores, I want to get all products not in stock, which have the latest 2 records in their history not in stock either.

In short, I want to know which products have been out of stock for 3 days.

I would also like to know how to build the index, so this query runs efficiently.

Comment: What is Product_Stock_History, how does it related, and how is it updated?

Comment: It just has the status field and the foreign key to relate it to the product. Each day the status of the product is updated with a new one, and the replaced one is added to the history.

Comment: Do all stores share the same product stock? Is Product_Stock_History related to a store?

Comment: No, stocks are not shared. Product_Stock_History is indirectly related to a store through a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.product_id
from Products p inner join Product_Stock_History ph
    on ph.product_id = p.product_id
where p.status <> 1 and ph.status <> 1 and ph.date > current_date - interval '3 days'
group by p.product_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Without referencing current date:

```
select p.product_id
from Products p inner join Product_Stock_History ph
    on ph.product_id = p.product_id
where p.status <> 1
qualify
    row_number() over (
        partition by p.product_id order by date desc
    ) = 1 and 
    count(*) over (
        partition by p.product_id order by date desc
        rows between current row and 1 following 
    ) filter (ph.status <> 1) = 2
```

As Postgres doesn't allow `qualify` you'll have to wrap those values up first.

```
with data as (
    select p.product_id,
        row_number() over (
            partition by p.product_id order by dt desc
        ) rn, 
        count(*) filter (where ph.status <> 1) over (
            partition by p.product_id order by dt desc
            rows between current row and 1 following 
        ) ct
    from Products p inner join Product_Stock_History ph
        on ph.product_id = p.product_id
    where p.status <> 1
)
select * from data where rn = 1 and ct = 2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ad252c27153626eb6c3e33fae5ab1eb7

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question though: can your query be adapted to work without using dates? Since history is ordered, the latest 2 records are from the latest 2 days.

Comment: You can't get order without some reference to a date or version number. Not sure what you mean by "is ordered." The first query would guarantee no gaps in the history. The second only looks for two rows.

Comment: What I mean is that the history table is updated everyday with a new record. So if I get the latest two records, I’m getting the statuses from the latest 2 days.

Comment: Yes, and by "latest two rows"  you still have to rely on some expectation that the values in some column represent the sequence. The placeholder for that above is "date".

Comment: Thanks @shawnt00 I think the interval quotes must contain the days modifier.

Comment: Yeah, I always have trouble remembering that syntax since I don't get to use it regularly.

Comment: By the way, could you clarify why you set 3 days in the interval, and 2 in the count(*), please?

Comment: @David that's just because I used strictly greater than. I was picturing it getting just the day before and the day before that. If there's a time component on your dates then it's probably also easier this way. Either way, two rows matching is the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select p.* from products p where productid in
Select productid from (
(Select PSH.productid, 
row_number() over (partition by PSH.productid  order by versionid desc) rn   from Product_Stock_History psh  where status<>1
) 
where
rn<=2) where date_col= current_date-3 and status<>1
```

Comment: That would only require one of the two histories to be zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question though: can your query be adapted to work without using dates? Since history is ordered, the latest 2 records are from the latest 2 days.

Comment: How do you identify them @David

Comment: I’m not sure I’m understanding your question. If you mean the history, I can just order it by id in descent order and limit by 2. I then can get the two last records (that correspond to the latest 2 days).

Comment: But how would you identify out of stock for your products with those 2 latest out of stock product versions that got out of stock for 3 days.

Comment: @David Do not use an auto-incremented ID as a surrogate for time order. There are many, many ways that assumption can break, and many restrictions it adds. Rows must always be inserted in real-time order. Every product must have a row for every day, none can ever be missed or deleted. If a mistake is made and a row is missing, you can't fix it.

Comment: Ohhh i just missed, OP is using surrogate for versioning yeah its possible then to adapt it without date but as you said @Schwern it will lead to issues thats correct unless these versions are further backed up if theres a scenario where version is missed. So, for OP my recommendation would also be to use a datatimestamp for versioning as SCD2 not autoincremental ids

Comment: Thank you for your solution and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with [a window query like Himanshu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70400130/14660) or a [group by/having like shawnt00](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70400174/14660). Or you can reorganize your schema to keep it simple.

Instead of storing a flag, store two timestamps: `stocked_at` and `out_of_stock_at`.

```
stores

products

store_products
  store_id references stores
  product_id references products
  unique(store_id, product_id)

  stocked_at timestamp,
  out_of_stock_at timestamp,
  check (stocked_at != out_of_stock_at)
```

Calculate its status from them.

```
select
  stocked_at > out_of_stock_at as in_stock
from store_products
```

You can make this convenient with a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-generated-columns.html).

```
  in_stock boolean generated always as (stocked_at > out_of_stock_at) stored
```

> In short, I want to know which products have been out of stock for 3 days.

```
select product_id
from store_products
where not in_stock
  and out_of_stock_at < current_timestamp - '3 days'::interval
```

> I would also like to know how to build the index, so this query runs efficiently.

Make a composite index on `(out_of_stock_at, stocked_at)`.

---

Status flags can often be replaced by join tables.

We can make one critical observation.

- A store's catalog is different from its inventory.

So we have...

- There are products.
- There are stores.
- Stores have a catalog of products they offer.
- Stores have an inventory of products they have in stock.

Expressed as tables and constraints...

```
stores

products

store_product_catalog
  store_id references stores
  product_id references products
  unique(store_id, product_id)

-- This allows a store to have inventory not in their catalog.
-- If you don't want that, give store_product_catalog an id
-- and relate store_product_inventory to store_product_catalog
store_product_inventory
  store_id references stores
  product_id references products
  unique(store_id, product_id)

  quantity
  updated_at
```

Write an update trigger to change store_product_inventory.updated_at when the store_product_inventory.quantity changes.

> In short, I want to know which products have been out of stock for 3 days.

```
select product_id
from store_product_inventory
where quantity = 0
  and updated_at < current_timestamp - '3 days'::interval
```

> I would also like to know how to build the index, so this query runs efficiently.

Make a composite index on `(quantity, updated_at)`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I don’t manage quantities in my example though. So I can’t apply your suggestion :(

Comment: @David I think you'll run into more problems if you don't separate the store catalog from inventory. You can replace `quantity` with an `in_stock` boolean. If you want to keep them together the same idea applies: use a timestamp instead of a flag. Store when it ran out of stock and when it was stocked. `out_of_stock_at > stocked_at` means out of stock. Then it's simple: `where out_of_stock_at > stocked_at and out_of_stock_at < current_timestamp - '3 days'::interval`.

Comment: @David I've updated the answer for the version using just timestamps. You can also have the history table if you still need it, but it becomes a daily snapshot of store_products.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!